# 67 dynamic checkboxes, how to disable all check boxes after 4 have been selected?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have 67 checkboxes, I would like to only allow the user to select 4 out of those 67. My issue right now is: I am not sure how to listen to the checkboxes and then see if they have been 4 checked.

```html
<table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-shadow--2dp" id="catTable">
<tbody style="width: 80%;">
    <tr style="width: 50%;">
        <?php
        $countCat = ceil(count($categories) / 11);
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($categories as $key => $value) {

            ?>

            <?php if ($i % $countCat == 0) { ?></tr><tr><?php } ?>

            <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">
                <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="<?php print $value['catID']; ?>">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="<?php print $value['catID']; ?>" class="mdl-checkbox__input">
                    <span class="mdl-checkbox__label"><?php print $value['categoryNames']; ?></span>
                </label>
            </td>


            <?php
            ++$i;
        }

        ?>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

What I have tried: (JQuery)

```
   var checkboxes = ''; // Not sure how to get the random 67 that have been selected.
if (checkboxes == 4) {
    $('#catTable').html('');
    $('#catTable').html(''); // create new table with the selected 4
}
```

Is it possible to use Jquery to listen in on the check boxes and once 4 have been selected remove the table and leave the 4 that's select. If the users wants to Remove or add a different category then create a remove or add button to bring back the category table ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes it is possible. What have you tried?

Comment: Updating post now

Comment: Post Updated, although I am stuck at the main part, which is trying to select the id's which where selected ?

Comment: I’ve added a button to my code that compiles all the selected checkbox values into an array and prints it to the console. Should be easily adaptable to your own core structure. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below acts as you would like, checking for change events on any dynamically created checkbox. It only acts upon checkboxes wrapped in an element with the class `.checkbox-group` with an attribute of `checkbox-limit`. This way the code can be applied to multiple checkbox lists on a single page with different limits, but does not fire unless a limit has been specified.

Only the checked checkboxes are still enabled after hitting the limit (so that you can deselect them and select another if you wish).

I've added a button to each group which demosntrates how you can gather the value attributed to the given selected checkboxes.

A little more complicated than some of the other answers... so it may be excessive, but also a little more versatile/powerful.

Hope it helps.

---

## Demo

```js
// Add change event trigger dynamically
$(document).on('change', '.checkbox-group[checkbox-limit] input[type="checkbox"]', function() {

  // Get limit from wrapper attribute
  var lim = $(this).closest(".checkbox-group").attr("checkbox-limit");

  // Get current number of selected checkboxes within this wrapper
  // You could change .find() for .children() to prevent it checking through the entire tree within the wrapper.
  var selCount = $(this).closest(".checkbox-group").find("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length

  // Check number of checked checkboxe against limit
  if (selCount == lim) {

    // Disable unchecked checkboxes (so user can still uncheck selected checkboxes)
    $(this).closest(".checkbox-group").find("input[type='checkbox']:not(:checked)").attr("disabled", true);

  } else {

    // Enable checkboxes if a checkbox is unchecked 
    $(this).closest(".checkbox-group").find("input[type='checkbox']:not(:checked)").removeAttr("disabled");

  }

});


// Add click event to gather values button
$(".gatherValues").click(function() {

  // Setup array to save values to
  var selValues = [];

  // Cycle through all checked checkboxes within that group
  $(this).closest(".checkbox-group").find("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {

    // Add value to array
    selValues.push($(this).attr("value"));

  });

  // Print to console
  console.log(selValues);

})
```

```css
.checkbox-group {
  border-left: 5px solid grey;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed grey;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

button {
  margin: 20px 00px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="checkbox-group" checkbox-limit="4">

  <p>Limit of 4 selection for this group.
  </p>

  <input type="checkbox" value="A">A<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="B">B<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="C">C<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="D">D<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="E">E<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="F">F<br>

  <button class="gatherValues">Compile Values</button>

</div>

<div class="checkbox-group">

  <p>No limit for this group, check does not fire as the .checkbox-group wrapper does not have a checkbox-limit attribute.</p>

  <input type="checkbox" value="1">1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="2">2<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="3">3<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="4">4<br>

  <button class="gatherValues">Compile Values</button>


</div>

<div class="checkbox-group" checkbox-limit="1">

  <p>Limit of 1 selection for this group.
  </p>

  <input type="checkbox" value="Option 1">Option 1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Option 2">Option 2<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Option 3">Option 3<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Option 4">Option 4<br>

  <button class="gatherValues">Compile Values</button>

</div>
```

Comment: I have used the `.map()` function instead `$('input.mdl-checkbox__input:checked').map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();`

Answer (score 3):

How about this code:

```
var limit = 4;
$('input.mdl-checkbox__input').on('change', function(evt) {
  if ($('input.mdl-checkbox__input:checked').length > limit) {
    this.checked = false;
  }
});
```

I think you will have an shorter loop with this code.

Comment: I tried logging the `var limit` it does not display anything if the boxes are checked or not ?

Comment: var `limit` just an number of the limit boxes. It can be used to compare with $('input.mdl-checkbox__input:checked').length, when checked checkbox is bigger than limit, uncheck that checkbox. It will not change if boxes are checked or not

Comment: My solution will work fine even if some boxes are already checked by PHP or javascript. If you find this helpful and better than other answers, please mark my answer as accepted answer, thank you!

Comment: Tested the fiddle and it is working as expected although, on my end it allows me to select the 4 but then I can select more than 4 as well without being able to remove the selected ones. I can select more than 4 and unable to remove any

Comment: Maybe you still have another js code associated with that checkboxes somewhere, If not, this code will works fine.

Comment: Awesome, simply placed it in a new document ready and boom it works. Thanks for taking the time to help my :)

Comment: @S4nc7ionP You're welcome! By the way, merry christmas ^^

Comment: Merry xMas to you too. How do I get the values of the selected check boxes ? I tried this `    var limit = 4;
    var o = [];
    $('input.mdl-checkbox__input').on('change', function(event) {
      if ($('input.mdl-checkbox__input:checked').length > limit) {
        this.checked = false;
      }
      if ($('input.mdl-checkbox__input:checked').val() !== 'undefined') {
        if (limit) {
            o = [$('input.mdl-checkbox__input:checked').val()];
        }
        console.log(o);
      }
    });`

Answer (score 2):

This will count number of checked checkboxes:

```
var selected_checkbox = 0;

//listen for checkbox change event, then count number of selected. put this inside document ready.
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){ 
   $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
      if($(this).is(":checked")){
         selected_checkbox ++;
      }

      if selected_checkbox == 4 then
          //hide the selection box here

          return false; //exit the checkbox loop
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: I tried adding `$('input[type=checkbox]').addClass('disabled');` into the if statement `selected_checkbox == 4` Turns out I think this might be a bad way to handle this large amount of checkboxes like @NdifrekeEkim stated. The user could check and uncheck any checkbox and it might break.

Comment: Disabling checkboxes on selected 4 is not a good idea, you can hide the selection list or prompting user to select only 4 if they selected more than max.

Answer (score 0):

I would say keep a global variable that you increment Everytime a checkbox event occurs. Then disable the default a action once the global variable size is 4.

Keep in mind that a user might uncheck an already checked box, so you should handle such cases so the global variable does not increment on such event.

Global variable is just nasty, but this should give you a head start

Comment: "Keep in mind that a user might uncheck an already checked box, so you should handle such cases so the global variable does not increment on such event.". I am trying to find a way around that x_x